# How to Show Related Products by Category in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

How to Show Related Products by Category in WordPress?

Products Category:

- Raised Access Flooring
- Ancillary Products
- Knauf Flooring
- Recycled Panels

E.g current page is Raised Access Flooring only display Ancillary Products, Knauf Flooring, Recycled Panels in Related Products.

I added code in single-products.php see below:

```
$orderby = 'name';
$order = 'random';
$hide_empty = true ;
$cat_args = array(
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_category', $cat_args );
if( !empty($product_categories) ){
    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
        $description = $category->description;
        echo '<div class="col-lg-6">';
        echo '<div class="card">';
        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
        $image = get_field('product_category', $category );
        if($image) {
            echo '<img class="card-img-top" src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] .'">';
        } else {
            echo '<img class="card-img-top" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/placeholder.png">';
        }
        echo '<div class="card-content">';
        echo '<h3>' . $category->name . '</h3>';
        echo '<p>';
        echo strlen($description) > 60 ? substr($description, 0, 100) . '...' : $description;
        echo '</p>';
        echo '<button class="button btn_medium btn_orange btn_squared btn_normal_style" href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >Discover more</button>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
else {
// no posts found
   echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no products were found' );
}
```

Comment: Refere this link please https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185011/exclude-category-by-slug-for-for-each-loop

Comment: @SudharshanNair I tried it before but not works in single-products.php

Comment: That solution is not based on page. It should work

Comment: Ok how do I add the code in single-products.php?

Comment: Create that functions in function.php file and use it in single-products.php

Comment: ["taxonomy"]=> string(16) "product_category", I only want to display related products e.g current page is Ancillary Products only display Raised Access Flooring, Knauf Flooring, Recycled Panels in single-products. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

First, get the terms of the category associated to the current product:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids') );
```

The id of current product is obtained with the function: get_the_id()

Second, get the other products that sharing the same terms (excluding from the result the current product):

```
$products = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post__not_in' => array(get_the_id()),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $terms,
            'include_children' => false
        )
    )
));
```

The complete code would be:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids') );
$products = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post__not_in' => array(get_the_id()),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $terms,
            'include_children' => false
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: thanks, I mean when they click any products category in single-products.php I would like to automatic hide for current product know what I mean

Comment: see screenshot: http://bubblei.co.uk/FGTvz5.png, so when click on Knauf Flooring, on Knauf Flooring page should have 2 products (Raised Access Flooring, Ancillary Products), how to automatic current page (like remove current product) in single-products.php only one file?

Comment: I paste the code above, you can edit it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51542355/10025598 :)

Comment: Please, look that in my code I'm getting only the terms' ids: $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids') );

Comment: Please look at: This only display current product not other 3 products display, have l done it wrong?

Comment: In your code you are not calling the get_posts function to get the products related to the terms.

Answer (score 0):

@MikeD This only display current product not other 3 products display, have l done it wrong?

```
`<?php
                $orderby = 'name';
                $order = 'random';
                $hide_empty = true ;
                $cat_args = array(
                    'orderby'    => $orderby,
                    'order'      => $order,
                    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
                    );
                $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_category', array('fields' => 'ids') );
                echo '<div class="container">';
                echo '<div class="row">';
                    foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
                        $term = get_term($term_id);
                        echo '<a href="' .get_term_link($term). '" ></a>';
                        echo '<div class="col-lg-6">';
                        echo '<div class="card">';
                        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'" >';
                        $image = get_field('product_category', $term );
                        if($image) {
                            echo '<img class="card-img-top" src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] .'">';
                        } else {
                            echo '<img class="card-img-top" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/placeholder.png">';
                        }
                        echo '<div class="card-content">';
                        echo '<h3>' . $term->name . '</h3>';
                        //echo $category->name;
                        //echo '<p>' . $category->description . '</p>';
                        echo '<p>';
                        echo strlen($description) > 60 ? substr($description, 0, 100) . '...' : $description;
                        echo '</p>';
                        //echo '<p>' . mb_strimwidth($category->description, 0, 30, "...") . '</p>';
                        echo '<button class="button btn_medium btn_orange btn_squared btn_normal_style" href="'.get_term_link($term).'" >Discover more</button>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</a>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Look that I'm getting an array with only the ids of the terms:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids') );
```

So, you should edit your snippet of code:

```
foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
```

as follows:

```
foreach ($terms as $key => $term_id) {
    $term = get_term($term_id);
```

By the way in your piece of code you are not using the $products variable with the array of related products, that was your initial question.